# Удаление элементов страницы в зависимости от роли?

Tags: angular2

Доброго времени суток,

Сделал роле-зависимые разделы. Сейчас же делаю роли на отдельные части раздела (к примеру скрыть убрать у обычного пользователя кнопку, или список, или ...)

Для этого в шаблоне просто пишу так:

```
<p [hasRole]="['admin', 'user']">Тестовый параграф которые видят только Админ и Пользователь</p>
<div [hasRole]="['admin']">Тестовый блок который видит только Админ</div>
```

Сама директива выглядит вот так:

```js
import { Directive, OnInit, ViewContainerRef } from '@angular/core';
import { Input } from "@angular/core/src/metadata/directives";

@Directive({
    selector: '[hasRole]'
})
export class HasRoleDirective implements OnInit {

    @Input() hasRole: Array<string>;

    private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef;

    constructor(viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef) {
        this.viewContainerRef = viewContainerRef;
    }

    ngOnInit() {
        this.checkRoles('user');
    }

    checkRoles(userRole: string) {
        console.log("Роль пользователя: " + userRole);
        if (!this.hasRole || this.hasRole.indexOf(userRole) != -1) {
            console.log("Есть доступ");
        } else {
            this.viewContainerRef.clear();
            console.log("Доступ запрещен");
        }
    }

}
```

Права пользователя на просмотр определяет отлично. Но вот не хочет удалять. Кто может подтолкнуть на решение?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Один человек подсказал решение (Алексей Зуев)

```
@Directive({
    selector: '[hasRole]'
})
export class HasRoleDirective implements OnInit {
    @Input() hasRole: Array<string>;

    constructor(private viewContainerRef: ViewContainerRef, 
                       private template: TemplateRef<any>) {}

    ngOnInit() {
        this.checkRoles('user');
    }

    checkRoles(userRole: string) {
        console.log("Роль пользователя: " + userRole);
        if (!this.hasRole || this.hasRole.indexOf(userRole) != -1) {
            console.log("Есть доступ");
            this.viewContainerRef.createEmbeddedView(this.template);
        } else {
            this.viewContainerRef.clear();
            console.log("Доступ запрещен");
        }
    }
}
```

И используем вот так:

```
<p *hasRole="['admin', 'user']"><Блок видят только Админ и Пользователь</p>
<div *hasRole="['admin']">Тестовый блок который видит только Админ</div>
```